# How to render specific fields from _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have pages like Home.cshtml and _layout.cshtml. Header, Menubar and Footer classes In _layout.cshtml. I want only Header and Footer to my Home.cshtml, How to get?

Following In _layout.cshtml

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="header">
         /*code*/
        </div>
        <div class="Menubar">
        /*code*/
        </div>
         <div class="Footer">
         /*code*/
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<body>
    @section header
    {
        <div class="header">
            /*code*/
        </div>
    }
    @section Menubar
    {
        <div class="Menubar">
            /*code*/
        </div>
    }
    @section Footer
    {
        <div class="Footer">
            /*code*/
        </div>
    }
</body>
```

**Home.cshtml**

```
@RenderSection("Menubar", false)
```

Note : I have added three section for your respective div. By default it will shows its content in all page. If you want to hide any section from any view then pass second parameter as false.

Comment: I try This but Other way around works. @section Menubar{} in Home.cshtml and @RenderSection("Menubar", false) method in _layout.

Comment: If you write @RenderSection("Menubar", false) method in _layout, then it will hide the Menubar section every time. So why are you adding Manubar section in the Home.cshtml.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I try it what we are suggest it works properly. But If I put sessions in _layout. I have to make ture in all other page as well. Am I correct? So I use another layout Bez I need 3 pages like that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your scenario?